# How could I solve Limitless Rendering in useEffect() for searchbar input?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

Here is my Functionality Code. I have tried my best but Can not solved this limitless error. when I check by console log everything is okay. but when I give setProducts it start.

```
 const Header = () => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useProducts();
    const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');`enter code here`
    
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const result = products?.filter(pro => pro.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()));

        setProducts(result);

        console.log(result);
    
    }, [searchText, products, setProducts]); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move code that is currently in useEffect and put in in useCallback function, and than call that function in useEffect. Right know you are setting products in use effect, and every time you change your products, useEffect triggers again. You can also fix this by removing products from use effect arguments.

Comment: I have removed products from dependency but only Console log show the answer. setProducts is not working. products is not rendering by this filter

Comment: const productFunc = useCallback(() => {
        const result = products?.filter(pro => pro.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()));

        console.log(result);
        setProducts(result);


    }, [searchText, products, setProducts])


    useEffect(() => {
        productFunc();

    }, [productFunc]);

Comment: I have write this way that useCallback function but still re-rendering limitlessly

Answer (score 0):

Here filter on products is returning an object reference and by updating products using `setProducts(result);` which updates `products`. which is causing to call useeffect again as 'products' is in dependency list of useEffect. So here is the process:

```
 1- filter products and return new array reference type
 2- set this new reference in products and console it
 3- react will check dependency array update for useEffect
 4- products key is updated so lets run useEffect callback again 
 5- oh again step 1 and step 2 will cause this loop to run again and 
 again
```

try removing products, setProducts from dependency array

Comment: I have removed products,and setProducts. Console log is still show perfect result but UI doesn't changing.. what can I do now?

Comment: how you are rendring UI? where is Ui implemention? How you are passing products to UI?

Comment: I am using custom hooks and send it to Products component